# Solve a typing problem on a helper with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am having a problem on typing a helper. My goal is to replace null values in an object with an empty string while maintaining my key values relationships in typescript

```js
// from 
{
    name: string | undefined
    url: string | null | undefined
    icon: string | null | undefined
}

// to
{
    name: string | undefined
    url: string | undefined
    icon: string | undefined
}
```

For this I use a `mapObjIndexed` from Ramda to replace each `null` by `''` nothing complicated

```js
const mapObjIndexed = (callBack, values) => {
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(values).map(entries => [
            entries[0],
            callBack(entries[1])
        ])
    )
}
```

Let's show you my problem

```js
import { mapObjIndexed } from "ramda"

// helper
const types = {
    isNull: (value: any): value is null => value === null
}

// test 1 => ts error
const nullToEmptyString = <T>(value: T | null): T | '' => types.isNull(value) ? '' : value

// test 2 => ts error
const nullToEmptyString2 = <T extends any>(value: T): T extends null ? '' : T => types.isNull(value) ? '' : value

// parser => ts error
const nullsToEmptyStrings = <T>(value: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | null }): { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | '' } => mapObjIndexed(nullToEmptyString, value)
```

The only way to make it work is to force the return values with as

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbziAhmA8gIwFYEkB2AJgKYAexhcAvnAGZQQhwBEUKIhKzAsAFB8B6AXAAWxADZhiUPgGMI+AM7wYATymK4AXkR84+uMEUA5AK7jxALjgAKAG4pxp4tZT5VASmsOnxQ5vxzcW0APjgfZ20tHUCLPio+QWEYYmU4AEZQuBhNaQYZXnkleFjxABUIAFFwNQBlGChgfABzbTgAHjKQ+0dnazK4AB84Uq84AeGAckmstQ0AOiMzCx7fDzgAfjhpuG9e4kTeIWzU+AAmWdyofLkFNNKK6rA6hqbmi51OuDIUok03VTdCIucZjAY-Yh-EZBTbbGb9WbqVKLExBVbOdZbHZ7XyHY6yNAwFBNAC0qggikUKEabj4tFM+FkMGACmhFkeNVU9UaLQAzOiQaNrNM6QymSz8GzylVOdy3rzOgAaIH7fpg0WM5msh4y55c158pUq3wI4ZC8ZDOG6XgGOBQYgwUxQSVzZFLNHAzFWnHOeKHIppe2KczwGJBDl6uUtGyjODHZg8Qp3eBBkMfKURl485o2M7rY5nQ5JOBgamKaSXb7XaC3YpSxSZ-XZzSfLoC6xIADaAGlDJKANbEcm0cYAXX6PdHltK1DGXd7TTgg+HY4n3anUxmNC0YVQGBwBBI5EIMfDuqzb0V4X2HjxwlLUHLUDgAHdgDARHAUC2wi-oP3a3uIIG3PJs3kUAB1d8RAAQRbDo22BDs4B7PslyHCARzKcdxknacYSoOcUIXAcMKwnCyjwzdqCyPcsDwIgyAoU92VAqNmivT0v00ec0OXTDV1w9dLR2BJ+COYQCWeYl8DJCkqRpfANXFbVgMbdjFDOI120QYi+LIwTKOEs0CKI1DF348i1w3K0xPpTUJXrdSDWaTTtKQ3TzNIldsOs-CLFna1bXtR1nWQNB6MPJiTx1J4LxaTibz9cTDldcZTgANX2eCED0AxaGAR8YGMdhiA2axlGzfzxDy-RxG-YrSvKuBKrearau+VBgHEZrWpadqbQMZQUEdRRmsmKQiDeGYphQWRZGIZ4KBm7Z7XpctCEmZKAxUTLsv6PbfByjqCqKkqQBBSYACkIBEfBJkVDr6uUc7LoAEQgYgHo64guqsbZsFu-B5kIT6AAEQGAWQGEUTCYHmeQQG+wb9GG0bhUmwhpse3gxMA3blHSAB9TIw1YuKwOjFJlCyo75lOl7So8Y4+taYYGRIAr8AoLIyCkJkedTcQYHxk5CaJ9NYtlFyzhsamYFp5xFHpwrGYu5nhFZy0OeILmeZ3b5SH5lJKCFkWkzreXid5NopcjFz+XlxXkQZxr1ZZlzqu1xi9cIUWraJgAWW2zwp9jHcOpX5jR0xFA1lhMbeZhLWYOaFqWwhk+GVhddjigs7gHXff9ZMxZgM4SZDiwQLDlzFDlyPUnjg2+eIAXTdSEM6GgOhVbd4gr2e-ur1+4lgkwUwSggeBWRjxR-dOCvJbUti66gj84IbmnsubsJW-bu1O+F7vn1d17B4a8-OrHuAJ6nmfJTnhflArm2yfEGvpebWWnZ344W6Nm3E2h9gzH1oD3M+pUL5qwHtfbqt9J4jGnnAWeRJRq2Dns1BMKdE4tALqneai0Tb4LWnnTO3tOZNAoAAbg8EAA)

I can't find any solution and my level in Typescript does not allow me to do it

Comment: Can you provide a typescript playground link?

Comment: Yes of course, i add link on bottom of my post

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this:

```js
const nullToEmptyString2 = <T extends any>(value: T): T extends null ? '' : T => types.isNull(value) ? '' : value
```

TypeScript does not support conditional types in a place of return type. In order to make it work end emulate `conditional typings` you need to [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature) it:

```js
function nullToEmptyString(value: null): ''
function nullToEmptyString<T,>(value: T): T
function nullToEmptyString<T,>(value: T | null): T | '' {
    return types.isNull(value) ? '' : value
}

const result = nullToEmptyString(null) // ""
const result2 = nullToEmptyString(2) // 2
```

As for this error:

```js
const nullsToEmptyStrings = <T>(value: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | null }): { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | '' } => mapObjIndexed(nullToEmptyString, value)
```

`mapObjIndexed` return type is not compatible with `{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] | '' }`.
You also can accomplish it with help of overloading:

```js
function nullsToEmptyStrings<T,>(value: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | null }): { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | '' }
function nullsToEmptyStrings<T,>(value: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | null }) {
    return mapObjIndexed(nullToEmptyString, value)
}
```

Comment: Your solution allows me to type my functions but causes problems on the return values. I updated the playground to highlight errors

Comment: @YannTouil you are using `optional` properties which are marked with `?` and explicit type `TestValues` for `testValues` const. Please provide exact type which you are expect

Comment: Typing is done by a validator, and it removes automatically empty string from body. I use in my body parser a hack to replace each empty string by a null to resolve this problem. In need reverse null to empty string after validation. I understand that this is not the best solution, but I must work with the constraints of this validator.